# MarkLogic search:search facet values not consistent with result set

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

We're using MarkLogic 9.0-4 `search:search` with facets defined in `options`. The returned facets contain values that are **NOT** in the result set.

For example, the search will return a facet with *city = 'Abbotsford', count = 5* and the result set doesn't contain any items that have *city = 'Abbotsford'*.

Furthermore, the problem is only occurring in our applications - not in query console, and only in some environments: 2 of our developers don't see the problem in their local development environments (1 does) and our test and production environments both show the problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

facet constraint looks like this:

```
<constraint name="city" label="City">
  <range type="xs:string" collation="http://marklogic.com/collation/en">
     <path-index xmlns:ata="http://kriteachings.org/ata">/ata:user/ata:profile/ata:addresses/ata:address[@type eq "primary-residence"]/ata:place/ata:details/ata:locality</path-index>
  </range>
</constraint>
```

searchable expression varies and generally looks like this

```
<searchable-expression xmlns:ata="http://kriteachings.org/ata">xdmp:directory("/user/")/ata:user[ata:trainer-info]</searchable-expression>
```

Some very relevant info: When I access the query console I'm a user with `admin` role and don't see the problem. I also don't see the problem when I give user accessing one of our apps `admin`. The problem (seeing values in facets that are not in the result set) only occurs when user is **NOT** `admin`.

Comment: Could you provide the details of the index behind the city facet? Could it be something related to case-sensitivity?

Comment: Thx @grtjn. I added the city search option constraint as an example. I get the expected results when I run in query console. When the code is executed through our app server we get the unexpected results I cite.

Comment: If you set search:search to run as unfiltered I bet you would see these results in your result set. What kinds of searches are you running? Most likely you have incorrect results being filtered out of the result set but not filtered out of the facets or document total (because they are calculated in an unfiltered fashion). The solution to get the facets and document total accurate is to add additional indexing to answer the questions that unfiltered search currently cannot. My personal guess is that you need the position indexes enabled judging by your path range index structure.

Comment: Thx @Rob S. We're using a searchable expression (now included above) that definitely eliminates the values we're seeing in the facets. The indexes used by our facets are hitting a larger set of data than the searchable expression.

Comment: Still perplexed that we're seeing the problem when running the search within one of our HTTP applications and not when running `search:search` through query counsel.

Comment: @Rob S - to answer your question more directly... There's not much text searching going on. Users mostly rely on facets to narrow the result set to something that's manageable for them.

Comment: @user2193014 Now that I see the searchable expression your problem is almost certainly that you need to enable the position indexes.

Comment: Thx @Rob S, Did you see my additional remarks about only seeing the problem when the user is not `admin`? I don't think it's a doc permission issue, we're seeing the right number of docs in the main result set.

Comment: @user2193014 Yes. Likely, your non-admin users see a smaller set of documents which are calculated correctly. You can see the right number of documents in your main result set as admin or non-admin because that resultset is filtered. The facets are calculated in an unfiltered fashion. So to get the right count as admin my thinking is that you can try enabling the positions indexes. Long term, I strongly recommend you move your document model to the envelope pattern so you no longer need path range indexes and position indexes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172765/discussion-between-user2193014-and-rob-s).

Comment: @user2193014 Not doing a chat.. Sorry. If you need immediate assistance consider reaching out to your MarkLogic Account team.